# Classical brain - quantum world

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-computer

A noted author (physicist) recently stated that he perceived the human brain as a classical mechanism powered by quantum mechanics. He went on to say that we are reaching the point where we are becoming reliant on quantum computers to solve the equations that our brains can't. It seems from following these thoughts that eventually we may rely on a whole class of machine systems that are beyond our intellectual reach. We'll be able to create them but not understand them. I see this as reaching a new level in evolution because we will be trusting a higher intelligence. At the moment how are the developments in quantum mechanics and computing benefiting society and where do you see us in 10 years?

(I realize this is a very general question - just starting somewhere)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The fundamental research (quantum mechanics etc.) is critical to continue, as it leads to practical solutions along with a deeper understanding of nature.  For example, many technologies like solar photovoltaic cells which are one of the key energy technologies have only been made possible by understanding of quantum mechanics starting around 100 years ago.  However, renewable sources like solar and wind are a good place to continue deeper research (more efficient/cleaner conversion to electricity etc.), in my opinion.  I hope this helps.